# Remove time from fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, css, fullcalendar

Im building a calendar using the fullcalendar.js library and is pulling event data from a json file. I've been trying to remove the times that are being shown and tried a few methods. One of them was to just hide the times using .fc-event-time { display: none; } but it still kept the large margins and extra space per tile.

[image: fullcalendar large margins]

Edit: The only code I'm writing is calling the fullcalendar method.

```
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        events: 'calendar.ashx'


    });
```

Comment: Please include relevant code.

Comment: Yes, I see it now. The error is on line #2712! No, but seriously, include code, we are not psychic.

Comment: This question doesn't actually need code, the question itself is clear enough to understand what OP wants

Answer (score 5):

Since v2.4.0 the option `displayEventTime` has been introduced.

`$("#calendar").fullcalendar({
    displayEventTime: false
});`

http://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/displayEventTime/

Comment: If I need to hide time for specific events, Can I do that?